# Where can I find latest official covid-19 requirements for Thailand?

Tags: covid-19, thailand

Apparently in the last few days there has been an announcement of return of covid-19 travel requirements for Thailand. I couldn't find an official page from Thai government with a simple search.

My main issue is that, possibly for some countries test and health insurance is required but I couldn't find an official list to see whether I'm affected.

I'm mainly looking to check for Iranian and Burmese citizens recently visited Netherlands, Germany, Iran, Turkey and Malaysia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After selecting Thailand in [IATA COVID-19 Travel Regulations Map](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php), it shows that as of right now only China and India are subject to a requirement of having travel insurance covering covid-19 expenses. For other countries vaccination or recovery certificate is sufficient.

I couldn't find any Thai official website stating this information in English, although I didn't search all the relevant ministry websites.